# Possible to “hide communities” on a single Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, hidden-communities

I'd like to hide my other accounts on a single Stack Exchange site, but not all of them. I found the "hide communities" section, but when I go there on the site I'd like to be more private and remove communities, it appears to hide them on all my accounts.

Is it possible to hide communities on a single site, but leave them publicly visible everywhere else?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot

Once you hide it from

**https://askubuntu.com/users/hidecommunities/current** say, it will be reflected directly in

**https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/hidecommunities/current**

The websites are interlinked and changing in one instantly reflects in other ones.

Comment: The answer is confusing, IMO it's enough to say "The list of Hidden Communities is cross site and changing it on one site have instant effect in all other sites."

Comment: @ShadowWizard tried simplifying it . thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hiding community(es) on the single site is not possible and useless.

If the community is not hidden anybody can access you [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/295527/bijendra?tab=accounts) via corresponding link in the currect community profile section.

Network profile contains a link of all your publicly visible accounts. So if hiding a community on the single site was possible it's unclear what should be displayed in such list. Hence it's not allowed.

Comment: Heh.. I accidentally used profile link from another answerer instead of questioner :)

Comment: *"if hiding a community on the single site was possible it's unclear what should be displayed in such list."* Why is it unclear? If a site is hidden *anywhere*, then don't show it in network profile. Seems clear enough. "We cannot hide the site in one place because it would show up in network profile, and we cannot hide it from network profile because it is not allowed to hide it in one place" sounds like circular reasoning.

Comment: @MaskedMan your solution is possible, but it's more hard to implement, because on each 'unhide' in single profile all other profiles should be checked for unhinding community. More over it will be possible to access hidden community (from network profile) by visiting profiles by chain.